# Regex match multiple data in URL for IIS Rewrite rule

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I'm looking for some help with a regex pattern for rewriting a URL. My URL structure is:

```
http://domain.com/[username]/[token]/[userid]/
```

The data types are:

- username = alphanumeric
- token = alphanumeric
- userid = numeric

An example with data:

```
http://domain.com/john1975/aBc123/123456789/
```

Using a regular expressions I'm trying to get a reference for each piece of data, so I can rewrite to:

```
index.asp?username={R:1}&token={R:2}&userid={R:3}
```

Also keep in mind the regex shouldn't be too greedy, so I can still access files such as:

```
http://domain.com/about.asp
http://domain.com/images/logo.png
```

The regex I've tried is:

```
^[0-9a-z]+/[0-9a-z]+/[0-9]+$
```

This doesn't match my example URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the trailing forward slash.  The regex should be :

```
^([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$
```

I'm assuming you're flagging it as case insensitive.  If not then you need

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$
```

You also need the brackets so you can call your back references, which are also wrong - you want to match on 1,2 and 3, not 0, which is the match of the whole expression.  They should read:

```
index.asp?username={R:1}&token={R:2}&userid={R:3}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This matches my example URL but it puts everything in the first reference. So I end up with: `index.asp?username=john1975/aBc123/123456789/&token=&userid=`. How can I get separate references with IIS rewrite?

Comment: ha I realised that and have just edited my answer to include that in - note that you need to bracket the parts of the rule that you wish to extract. R:0 refers to the whole thing, and then R:1 etc refer to specific matches indicated by the order in which the brackets occur.